# bcdedit /copy syntax not correct

Tags: powershell, windows-10, hyper-v, bcdedit

I'm trying to run Oracle Virtual Box on my work laptop.  I'm getting an error saying that it can't run because I'm running Hyper-v.  I'm trying to follow the instructions at [Scott Hanselman's Blog](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx), which have worked for me in the past on my personal laptop with a similar issue.

I run:

```
bcdedit /copy {current} /d "No Hyper V"
The copy command specified is not valid.
Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance.
The parameter is incorrect.
```

I run

```
bcdedit /copy {current} /d /?

This command creates a copy of the specified boot entry.

bcdedit [/store <filename>] /copy {<id>} /d <description>

    <filename>      Specifies the store to be used. If this option is not
                    specified, the system store is used. For more information,
                    run "bcdedit /? store".

    <id>            Specifies the identifier of the entry to be copied.
                    For more information about identifiers, run
                    "bcdedit /? ID".

    <description>   Specifies the description to be applied to the new entry.

Example:

The following command creates a copy of the specified operating system boot
entry:

    bcdedit /copy {cbd971bf-b7b8-4885-951a-fa03044f5d71} /d "Copy of entry"
```

and

```
bcdedit /? ID

IDENTIFIERS

Many of the Bcdedit commands require identifiers. An identifier
uniquely identifies entries contained in the store. An identifier takes the
form of a globally unique identifier, or GUID. A GUID has the following format,
where each "x" represents a hexadecimal digit.

    {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}

For example:

    {d2b69192-8f14-11da-a31f-ea816ab185e9}

The position of the dashes (-) and the braces at the beginning and end of the
GUID are required.

Several entries can be identified by well-known identifiers. If an entry has a
well-known identifier, BCDedit displays it in output unless the /v command-line
switch is used. For more information, run "bcdedit /? /v".

The well-known identifiers are as follows:

    {bootmgr}               Specifies the Windows boot manager entry.

    {fwbootmgr}             Specifies the firmware boot manager entry,
                            specifically on systems that implement the
                            Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI) specification.

    {memdiag}               Specifies the memory diagnostic application entry.

    {ntldr}                 Specifies a OS loader (Ntldr) that can be used
                            to start operating systems earlier than Windows
                            Vista.

    {current}               Specifies a virtual identifier that corresponds to
                            the operating system boot entry for the operating
                            system that is currently running.
```

but it looks like there's nothing wrong with my syntax, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Powershell seems to have been the problem.  In my powershell prompt I typed cmd and then ran `bcdedit /copy {current} /d "No Hyper V"` with no errors.

Answer (score 13):

```
bcdedit --% /copy {current} /d "No Hyper V"
```

stop-parsing symbol `--%`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing

Answer (score 10):

I had exactly the same problem. I found the solution on this [documentation of bcdedit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/changing-the-friendly-name-of-a-boot-entry) from microsoft. This is just a problem when you are using powershell instead cmd.

You just have to set the identifier of the boot entry into double quotes:

```
bcdedit /copy "{current}" /d "No Hyper-V"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when the shell/command prompt is not running as administrator.

When not running as administrator, windows does not allow any read or write to BCD

```
> bcdedit /v
The boot configuration data store could not be opened.
Access is denied.
```

Running the shell or command prompt as administrator solved the issue.